# Using NDSolveValue to find maximum difference between two functions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I have a set of differential equations I'm trying to solve with various parameters and compare some of the functions. Here is the naive approach:

```
F[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] :=
 NDSolve[{
  f1'[t] == b1 f1[t] - a1 f1[t] f2[t],
  f2'[t] == b2 f2[t] - a2 f1[t] f2[t],
  f1[0] == 1, f2[0] == 1},
 {f1, f2},
 {t, 0, 10}
]
```

(Note: These are not my DEs. Just a trivial example. Additional complications of my DEs should not affect how we approach the question I have.)

So my goal is to find the difference between the functions. Proceeding naively, we can just integrate to find any $p$-norms we want, except $p=\infty$, which I've used Maximize for instead:

```
G[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] :=
 Block[{s1, s2},
  {s1, s2} = ReplaceAll[{f1, f2}, F[a1, a2, b1, b2][[1]]];
  {
   NIntegrate[Abs[s1[t] - s2[t]], {t, 1, 10}],
   NIntegrate[Abs[s1[t] - s2[t]]^2, {t, 1, 10}]^(1/2),
   Maximize[{Abs[s1[t] - s2[t]], 0 <= t <= 10}, t][[1]]
   }
  ]
```

However, this is quite slow. The faster version I have can only compute the norms for $p<\infty$ by making a straightforward adjustment to combine the functions `F` and `G` into one. So first, for comparison, strip out the extra stuff from `G` to get less output:

```
G2[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] :=
 Block[{s1, s2},
  {s1, s2} = ReplaceAll[{f1, f2}, F[a1, a2, b1, b2][[1]]];
  {
   NIntegrate[Abs[s1[t] - s2[t]], {t, 1, 10}],
   NIntegrate[Abs[s1[t] - s2[t]]^2, {t, 1, 10}]^(1/2)
   }
  ]
```

And here's our new `G3`:

```
G3[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] :=
 NDSolveValue[
  {
   f1'[t] == b1 f1[t] - a1 f1[t] f2[t], 
   f2'[t] == b2 f2[t] - a2 f1[t] f2[t],
   f1[0] == 1, f2[0] == 1,
   L1'[t] == Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]], L1[0] == 0,
   L2'[t] == Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]^2, L2[0] == 0
   },
  {L1[10], L2[10]^(1/2)},
  {t, 0, 10}
  ]
```

The new `G3` is about 100x faster than `G2`, but it's missing the $p=\infty$ norm that I'd like to have. I've run out of ideas, and I have an itch in the back of my brain that says "it's a simple trick you're overlooking." Something internal to `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` that lets me track the value of some quantity at each time-step and update it (i.e. `Abs[s1[t]-s2[t]]`)? This sounds like something that may exist, but I'm not finding it in the web of documentation.

The only practical idea I came up with was just doing something like $p=1000$ as well as $p=1,2$, which could be an approximate $p=\infty$ norm. It fits nicely in the existing code for `G3` and returns fairly useful data, but it's actually *slower* than the original `G`.

My intention is to use this to compare over, say, hundreds or thousands values of *each* of `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, `b2`, which means I do not have the luxury of saying "1 second is fine, even if I could do it in 0.05 seconds."

Any thoughts on getting the $p=\infty$ norm at similar speeds as we find the other two quantities?

Comment: Maybe you can add `WhenEvent[f1'[t]-f2'[t]==0, Sow[Abs[f1[t]-f2[t]]]]` and `Reap` the extrema?

Comment: Please provide the specific `{a1, a2, b1, b2}` that you wish used for timing purposes.  `G3` generates error messages for `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Comment: All the time goes into doing `NIntegrate`, and `G3` probably is faster than `G2`, because the integration is coarser.

Comment: For fixed test values, try `0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.07` respectively. For randomized testing, try `RandomReal[{0.1, 10}], RandomReal[{0.1, 10}], RandomReal[{0.01, 1}], RandomReal[{0.01, 1}]` .

Comment: Sorry, please reverse those: For fixed test values, try `0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.2` respectively. For randomized testing, try `RandomReal[{0.01, 1}], RandomReal[{0.01, 1}],  RandomReal[{0.1, 10}], RandomReal[{0.1, 10}]` . I had "a" and "b" mixed-up when I made those up, although they might also work. Again, this is not the actual set of DEs and I'm not looking to optimize beyond solving the problem mentioned.

Comment: I am looking at Carl's suggestion to see if I can make it work. One thing that may complicate the issue is that the greatest difference may occur at the end of the time-step in this example system. It might (although unlikely) occur in the real system too. I will have to look into something to `||` with the event in the `WhenEvent` to trigger at the end of the `NDSolve`.

Comment: Just add Abs[f1[10]-f2[10]] and Abs[f1[0]-f2[0]] to the list of extrema.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The OP is asking how to compute the ∞-norm, which is what my suggestion aims to achieve.

Comment: The speed of the $p=1,2$ norms are as fast as they're going to be, I think. The goal is either computing the $p=\infty$ norm within the `NDSolveValue` or else computing the $p=1,2$ norms in a way that is efficient and allows us to compute the $p=\infty$ norm. I think you are each approaching this from one of these two angles.

Comment: p == 1000 is nearly as fast as p == 1, with the answer 2.366285331305866415.

Comment: Another idea is to include: `diff'[t] == f1'[t] - f2'[t], diff[0]==0` in your ODE, and then do `Max[Abs@diff["ValuesOnGrid"]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, after trying a few different implementations and combinations of the ideas proposed by Michael E2, bbgodfrey, and Carl Woll.

```
G5[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_] :=
 Block[{max = 0},
  NDSolveValue[
   {
    f1'[t] == b1 f1[t] - a1 f1[t] f2[t], 
    f2'[t] == b2 f2[t] - a2 f1[t] f2[t], f1[0] == 1, f2[0] == 1,
    L1'[t] == Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]], L1[0] == 0,
    L2'[t] == Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]^2, L2[0] == 0,
    Linf[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[f1'[t] - f2'[t] == 0,
     max = Linf[t]; Linf[t] -> Max[max, Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]]
     ]
    },
   {L1[10], L2[10]^(1/2), Max[Linf[10], Abs[f1[10] - f2[10]]]},
   {t, 0, 10},
   DiscreteVariables -> {Linf}
   ]
  ]
```

This seems very competitive with `G3`, taking about 50-75% more time (quite reasonable considering we are asking for more information).

I am not sure how to choose best answer, as the two answers provided valuable input which I distilled into this -- which I think represents a sort of minimal change from `G3` to get what I was looking for.

Without choosing a best answer yet, I should thank the three contributors. Your input was very helpful and valuable. Perhaps I will leave this open a bit longer in case anyone else has another interesting perspective to add.

Comment: I did some looking at it seems like it is common to pick one's own answer in a situation like this. Sorry if it is any offense to the other helpful answers, which certainly make up the foundation of my approach to this final answer I came up with. (I will add, in practice, this implementation was more useful for me because I was also working with a much more complex system, with more DEs, no fixed end time, greater complexity/time-costs, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

From `RepeatTiming` of the various functions for the test parameters given in a comment,

```
G2[.05, .07, .1, .2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0386, {8.42801, 3.41397}} *)
G3[.05, .07, .1, .2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0010, {8.47102, 3.41433}} *)
s = Flatten@F[.05, .07, .1, .2]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00083, Null} *)
```

we see that `G3` is about 40 times faster `G2` but its results differ from those of `G2` by about several tenths of a percent.  More importantly, `F` is about the same speed as `G3`, indicating that essentially all of the extra time required by `G2` goes to `NIntegrate`.  This suggests that `G3` is about the best that can be done, apart from reducing the accuracy required of `NDSolve`.

Here is an alternative approach.

```
c = (f1 /. s)["Coordinates"] // Flatten;
v1 = (f1 /. s)["ValuesOnGrid"];
v2 = (f2 /. s)["ValuesOnGrid"];

(* p == 1 *)
(Sum[Abs[v1[[i]] - v2[[i]]] (c[[i + 1]] - c[[i - 1]])/2, {i, 2, Length[c] - 1}]
    + Abs[v1[[1]] - v2[[1]]] c[[1]]/2 + Abs[v1[[-1]] - v2[[-1]]] (c[[-1]] - c[[-2]])/2) 
    // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00011, 8.48083} *)

(* p == 2 *)
(Sum[Abs[v1[[i]] - v2[[i]]]^2 (c[[i + 1]] - c[[i - 1]])/2, {i, 2, Length[c] - 1}] 
    + Abs[v1[[1]] - v2[[1]]]^2 c[[1]]/2 + Abs[v1[[-1]] - v2[[-1]]]^2 (c[[-1]] - c[[-2]])/2)
    ^(1/2) // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00012, 3.42291} *)
```

This alternative, which simply uses the trapezoidal integration rule on the raw data produced by `NDSolve` is at least as fast and as accurate as `G3`.  Moreover, it offers the advantage of separating the computation of `{f1, f2}` from the computation of the norms.  Note that `G3` and the approach just given must have the same intrinsic accuracy, because they both rely directly on the same raw data from `NDSolve`.

**Addition**

```
{* p == 10 *)
(* {0.00012, 2.20872} *)
(* p == 100 *)
(* {0.00012, 2.33251} *)
(* p == 1000 *)
(* {0.00017, 2.366285331305866415} *)
(* p == 10000 *)
(* {0.00024, 2.3696899749044680823} *)
```

The last few compare well with the `p == Infinity` norm for the array `Abs[v1 - v2]`, namely

```
(* p == Infinity *)
Max[Abs[v1 - v2]]
(* 2.37007 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I wonder, have you modified `G3` in some way so that `F[G3[ -- ]]` is syntactically correct? (See: 5th line of first code block.)

Comment: @KellenMyers  Typo, now fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A way to get the infinity norm straight out of `NDSolveValue` is with

```
{WhenEvent[f1'[t] - f2'[t] == 0,                      (* critical point *)
  max = norm[Infinity][t];                            (* update  max and *)
  norm[Infinity][t] -> Max[max, Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]]   (* norm[Infinity] *)
  ],
 norm[Infinity][0] == (max = Abs[f1[0] - f2[0]]) (* diff. of ICs *)}
```

and return the value

```
Max[norm[Infinity][10], Abs[f1[10] - f2[10]]]
```

from `NDSolveValue`. (Here `max` is a non-diff.-eq. variable that should be initialized to the absolute difference of the functions at the initial condition.)

Here's a function that computes a list of norms `p`:

```
ClearAll[G4];
G4[a1_, a2_, b1_, b2_, p_: {1, 2, Infinity}] :=
  Module[{normlist, norm, max, f1, f2, t, pode, pnorm, discvar},
   (* code to compute p-norm in NDSolve[] *)
   pode[Infinity] := {WhenEvent[f1'[t] - f2'[t] == 0,
      max = norm[Infinity][t]; 
      norm[Infinity][t] -> Max[max, Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]]],
     norm[Infinity][0] == (max = Abs[f1[0] - f2[0]]) (* diff. of ICs *)};
   pode[pp_] := {norm[pp]'[t] == Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]^pp, norm[pp][0] == 0};
   (* code for the return value of the p-norm in NDSolveValue[] *)
   pnorm[Infinity] := Max[norm[Infinity][10], Abs[f1[10] - f2[10]]];
   pnorm[pp_] := norm[pp][10]^(1/pp);
   (* DiscreteVariables *)
   discvar[{___, Infinity, ___}] := {norm[Infinity]};   
   discvar[_] := {Nothing};

   normlist = Flatten[{p}];
   NDSolveValue[{
     f1'[t] == b1 f1[t] - a1 f1[t] f2[t], 
     f2'[t] == b2 f2[t] - a2 f1[t] f2[t], f1[0] == 1, f2[0] == 1,
     pode /@ normlist},
    pnorm /@ normlist,
    {t, 0, 10},
    DiscreteVariables -> discvar[normlist]]
   ];
```

Include the infinity norm makes it about three times slower, but only three times.  It's going to be faster, I think, to `Reap` and `Sow[Abs[f1[t] - f2[t]]]` at critical points and then post-process the reaped local extrema, as Carl Woll suggested.

```
G4[0.3, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1] // RepeatedTiming      (* default is p = {1, 2, Infinity} *)
(*  {0.0044, {11.4175, 4.74135, 2.45422}}  *)

G4[0.3, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1, {1, 2}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0016, {11.4175, 4.74135}}  *)
```

Comment: Is the line ` norm[Infinity][0] == (max = Abs[1 - 1]) ` correct? Do you want `f1[0]-f2[0]` instead of `1-1`? Probably obvious, but I want to make sure I follow.

Comment: @KellenMyers Yes, `Abs[f1[0] - f2[0]]` -- I didn't think it would work. I wasn't sure the values would be substituted.  Thanks.